# C# -- how does one access a class' static member, given an instance of that class?

Tags: c#, static, gettype

In C#, suppose you have an object (say, `myObject`) that is an instance of class `MyClass`.
Using `myObject` only, how would you access a static member of `MyClass`?

```
class MyClass
    {
    public static int i = 123 ;
    }

class MainClass
    {
    public static void Main()
        {
        MyClass myObject = new MyClass() ;
        myObject.GetType().i = 456 ; //  something like this is desired,
                         //  but erroneous
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you can't reference it more directly? There's a bit of code smell here.

Comment: My method takes a parameter that is of type Block, but the actual argument passed is of a class that is of one of several *subclasses* of Block, and each subclass is to have its own copy of the static member (this role played by "i" in the code of my question).

Comment: IMHO, quite often the best answer to "How do I do this?" is "Don't do that."   I strongly suspect this is one of those times.

Comment: Yes, this feels like an ugly (and slow) way to do it compared with having a polymorphic property which could always return the appropriate value.

Comment: (See my edited answer for an example of that.)

Comment: @tnyfst Counting on the freedom of speech, I'd say "quite often the best available answer...". I came to hear this answer too many times, almost systematically. But IMHO users should not be deprived of choice. Unless it's a matter of unintended unavailabilty, of course, which would be perfectly alright and understandable. But to the question "I want to do this" replying "you don't want that" instead of "not advisable but you could do it this way" is clearly a sign of language shortcomings, and moreover, the sign is presented in offensive wrapping.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'd have to use reflection:

```
Type type = myObject.GetType();
FieldInfo field = type.GetField("i", BindingFlags.Public |
                                     BindingFlags.Static);
int value = (int) field.GetValue(null);
```

I'd generally try to avoid doing this though... it's very brittle. Here's an alternative using normal inheritance:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual int Value { get { return 10; } }
}

public class MyOtherClass : MyClass
{
    public override int Value { get { return 20; } }
}
```

etc.

Then you can just use `myObject.Value` to get the right value.

Comment: With the details posted it would seem over kill since he can just reference MyClass.StaticMember

It only really matters if myObject could be more than one Class and you can't know which at development.

Comment: @Robert: That's exactly his situation though. See the comments to the question.

Comment: But it's supposed to be static. I'm confronting this problem too.

Comment: @mireazma: It's really not clear what you mean, I'm afraid. What's supposed to be static?

Comment: @JonSkeet wow, you're fast. `Value` is supposed to be static. I am personally looking for a solution to get out of the exact situation where I need (1) the field to be static, and at the same time (2) access the "right" `Value` according to runtime subclass.

Comment: @mireazma: Then as per my answer, you either need to use reflection, or introduce a virtual instance member that is overridden in every subclass. The type system of .NET simply doesn't have the sort of "static polymorphism" you're looking for.

Answer (score 14):

If you have control of MyClass and need to do this often, I'd add a member property that gives you access.

```
class MyClass
{
    private static int _i = 123;

    public virtual int I => _i;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You simply have to use: `MyClass.i`

To elaborate a little, in order to use a static member, you have to know about the class. And having an object reference is irrelevant. The only way an object would matter is when you would have 2 distinct classes that both have an identical looking member:

```
class A { public static int i; }
class B { public static int i; }
```

But `A.i` and `B.i` are completely different fields, there is no logical relation between them. Even if B inherits from A or vice versa.

Comment: I'd like to be able to access static member <code>i</code> using reference <code>myObject</code>, only.

Comment: Johannes, I read that, but don't think it is a real(istic) question.

Comment: JaysinFix, in the sample you give MyClass.i is the only sensible answer, maybe you can explain it a little better? This one begs for a 'why'

Comment: Henk, see my above comment under the question, itself.