# How to access a type's implemented static abstract interface members by having only a type without using reflection?

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

How to access a type's implemented static *abstract* interface members by having only a type and using the interface type itself? Any way to do that?
I'm *not* talking about accessing static members via reflection.

example:

```cs
public interface ISomeInterface
{
   static int SomeProperty {get; set;}
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
   static abstract int SomeProperty {get; set;} = 2;
}

var implementingType = typeof(SomeClass);

ISomeInterface interface = /* How? */
```

Is there any way  of getting the value **without** using the common way by using reflection to acces a static member like this

```cs
void Method {
   var value = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperty("SomeProperty").GetValue(null);
   value = typeof(ISomeInterface).GetProperty("SomeProperty").GetValue(null);
}
```

Casting is a concept which only works with instances so it cannot be used for Type definitions.

Comment: Entirely speculation, but I wonder if you can get the interface-map from SomeClass (something like GetInterfaceMap, not at a computer), resolve the method that implements that API you're looking for from that, and invoke that method directly with a null target? Very very far from efficient, note. If you're doing this more than once, you'd want to cache the resolved method, probably after creating a delegate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# -- how does one access a class' static member, given an instance of that class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125647/c-sharp-how-does-one-access-a-class-static-member-given-an-instance-of-that)

Comment: Sadly no. I explicitely wrote, that this already can be done by reflection. furthermore: since casting is a concept which only works for object instances, it cannot be used here.

Comment: @SvenKrauter A "no" is a valid answer. Also static interface members is C# 8, not C# 10.

Comment: @GSerg yes the answer is no. See my answer. And yes you're right, with c#8. What I meant was static **abstract** members which are c#10. Hence I corrected the title and text regarding this.

Comment: ?? abstract? As [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-abstract-properties) says: _" An abstract property declaration does not provide an implementation of the property accessors -- it declares that the class supports properties, but leaves the accessor implementation to derived classes."_ I.e. you are not supposed to access an abstract property! Wanting/needing to do so is a code smell/anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

First, abstract keyword should be applied to interface method, not class. If interface method is not abstract your question is pointless anyway.

Static abstract interface methods are irrevelant here because you cant call any static method without specifying type name, in other words you cant call static methods on instances.

Fallowing is my approach to your question, which is as almost as fast as direct call (it cant be inlined though.) Using static readonly managed function pointers to hold constructed method addresses we can avoid delegate object creation and method address will be treated as constant value by jit but no need to complicate things here..

```cs
class Program
{

    public interface ISomeInterface
    {
        abstract static int SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
    {
        static int ISomeInterface.SomeProperty { get; set; } = 2;
    }

    public class SomeClass2 : ISomeInterface
    {
        static int ISomeInterface.SomeProperty { get; set; } = 3;
    }

    public static int GetProp<T>() where T : ISomeInterface
    {
        return T.SomeProperty;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(SomeClass)) as ISomeInterface;
        //obj.SomeProperty <= no hopes here..

        var methodDefinitation = typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(GetProp), System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

        var @delegate = methodDefinitation.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeClass)).CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>)) as Func<int>;
        var @delegate2 = methodDefinitation.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeClass2)).CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>)) as Func<int>;
        var result1 = @delegate(); //2
        var result2 = @delegate2(); //3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking again about the question and what I wanted to do, the answer is no.

There is no way of using the interface type to access the overridden value of a static abstract interface member in an implementing class other than reflection and accessing the static prop by using

```cs
GetProperty(name).GetValue(null)
```

Edit: SO is not the place for suggestions, but I thought about something like:

```cs
ISomeInterface a = (ISomeInterface)typeof(SomeImplementingClass);
var value = a.SomeInterface.SomeProperty;
```

or

```cs
var value = typeof(SomeImplementingClass).As<ISomeInterface>().SomeProperty;
var value = ISomeInterface.FromType<SomeImplementingClass>().SomeProperty;
```

...where '.As()' throws an exception if the interface isnt implemented.
Both of these examples aren't supported.